# Integration of independent Brownian motions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am wondering if the following integral of stochastic Brownian motions has an analytical solution?

$$
\int_{0}^{t}e^{\nu \tilde{V}_{\tau} - \frac{1}{2}\nu^{2}\tau}d\tilde{W}_{\tau}
$$

where $\tilde{W}_{\tau},\tilde{V}_{\tau}$ are two independent Brownian motions, $N(0,\tau)$. I did some search on the subject and found this [reference](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5823.pdf) based on Bougerol [work](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIHPB/AIHPB_1983__19_4/AIHPB_1983__19_4_369_0/AIHPB_1983__19_4_369_0.pdf) (in french). However, I cannot find a satisfactory answer.

In the papers they give 2 results:

$$
\sinh(\tilde{V}_{t}) \stackrel{law}{=} \int_{0}^{t}e^{\tilde{V}_{s}}d\tilde{W}_{s}
$$

or

$$
\sinh(\tilde{V}_{t}+\tilde{\varepsilon}t) \stackrel{law}{=} \int_{0}^{t}e^{\tilde{V}_{s}+s}d\tilde{W}_{s}
$$

where $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ is a symmetric Bernoulli variable between {-1,1}.

I am looking for an answer like that but for the integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{t}e^{\nu \tilde{V}_{\tau} - \frac{1}{2}\nu^{2}\tau}d\tilde{W}_{\tau} \stackrel{law}{=} \dots
$$

Thanks in advance for your replies.

*I previously posted this question on Mathoverflow but Mathematics seems to be more adapted.*